# Log information in Azure Postgresql server

Tags: postgresql

I have checked server logs in Azure server and see some log records as bellow:

> LOG:  connection received: host=xxx port=xxx pid=xxx LOG:  connection
>   authorized: user=xxxdatabase=xxx SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.1,
>   cipher=xxx, compression=off)
>   **LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**.

At: [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/21532.1473431951%40sss.pgh.pa.us)
It mentioned about error code `WSAECONNRESET`. 
But from MS document [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)
 This code don't mean about

> could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Assume this issue related to `WSAECONNRESET`, so the developer need to add close command in their application to end their session?

Thanks,
Dokota.